# Which configuration for graphics

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

Apart from being a programmer I am also a hobby 3D designer, 3D artist, webdesigner and photographer. My current XMG C405 laptop is getting old and has a few issues, the main one being, it only has one HDMI out.

Now I want to replace that old machine with a new one, but I cannot quite find any reliable information about 3D creation performance. There is a ton of benchmarks for gaming but that is not very comparable by my experience.

So here are the two setups I had in mind. One using Ryzen and one using Coffee Lake. The reason why I consider Ryzen is the better multi core performance. Also all the 3D and Adobe software I use supports multi core.

The Ryzen setup

- CPU: Ryzen 7 2700X
- MB: ASUS PRIME X470-PRO
- GPU: SAPPHIRE Radeon RX 580 PULSE
- RAM: G.Skill DIMM DDR4-3200 32GB manufacturer code: F4-3200C16S-16GVK
- SSD: Samsung 960 EVO 1TB

The Coffeelake setup is basically the same just the CPU and mainboard are different

- CPU: Core i7-8700K
- MB: ASUS ROG STRIX Z370-F Gaming
- GPU: SAPPHIRE Radeon RX 580 PULSE
- RAM: G.Skill DIMM DDR4-3200 32GB manufacturer code: F4-3200C16S-16GVK
- SSD: Samsung 960 EVO 1TB

Which one would you consider better for 3D graphics and photography. Would you switch any parts?

EDIT: What would you guys say about the graphics card for rendering and graphics? I checked out the nvidia GTX 1060 but it seemed a bit expensive for the few percent more performance, do you have any suggestion?

If you would like to see what kind of art I make you can checkout here: http://design.ulbricht.codes/
<sup>Yes I own a hipster domain</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The machines are identical from what you've shown, save the processor and motherboard.   That really makes this a "which is better for my purpose, a current gen Ryzen or a current gen i7".

When it comes down to it, the i7 handles single-threaded to quad-threaded apps better than the Ryzen, but the Ryzen shines when used in 4+ thread applications.  Their current pricing is nearly identical.

Since the 2700x is a new processor (relatively), there is less anecdotal information available and it's hard to find information about overclocking.  Still, [what information we do have suggests that the two are pretty comparable.](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-8700K-vs-AMD-Ryzen-7-2700X/3937vs3958) If you're a particular fan of one company over the other, you can probably just go with your fandom preference and not have it bite you (which is rare for fans of any tech company).  If you don't care, I'd buy whichever cost less, unless some of your rendering software can take advantage of more than 4 cores (AMD) or specifically does not (Intel).

Comment: As far as I know all Adobe applications can use more than 4 cores, so you would recommend the Ryzen? The rendering of the final images is done in the cloud anyway, saves a lot of time. I adjusted the question a bit, cause I am unsure about the graphics.

Comment: I personally prefer nVidia graphics cards, but AMD ones aren't bad.  They were ATI before AMD bought up the company.  You're doing a lot of 2D rendering, so texture memory and CPU are what will matter most.  If you get the 1060, get the 6GB variant.  If the rx580, get the 8GB variant.  for what you're doing, they will perform very similarly.

Comment: Actually I mainly use ray tracers for the rendering of the files. On my local machine I only do the preview rendering, the images you see on Behance are all cloud rendered. Thanks for the advice :)